# Remove Alhambra/Sharan seat cover

Tags: seat

Does anyone have any tips on how I can remove the front seat back panel from a Alhambra/Sharan 2014 registration?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: Are you looking to remove the entire thing cover or just the back panel itself? If construction is like any other seat cover, you'd have to remove the entire cover, then replace the section you are looking to replace.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm just looking to remove the back panel.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you'll have to remove any head rest (if there), then there will be what is called "hog rings" which you'll have to pull (be prepared with new ones to replace). After that you can pull the cover off, starting at the bottom and pulling it back up over itself, so when it comes off it will be inside out. Then you'll have it off and you can replace the piece you are looking to replace. Goes back on in opposite order (easier said than done).